# PHP or MySQL is fetching all rows from the tags table and not just what the intermediary term_tags table says it should

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables:

- terms: (term_id...)
- tags: (tag_id, tag_name); and
- term_tags (term_id, tag_id)

term_tags is an intermediary table with a couple foreign key constraints to term_id and tag_id in the terms and tags tables respectively.

I am trying to pull the tags associated to a given term id using the PHP code below.

```
    <?php
    include('includes/config.php');
    $sql = "SELECT tag_name FROM tags JOIN term_tags WHERE term_id = ?";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    if($stmt->execute(array($_GET['id']))){
        while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
            echo $row['tag_name'], "<br />";
        }
    }
    ?>
```

What happens is all rows are fetched from the tags table, I only want the tags associated with a given term id. I'm not sure if it's my SQL statement or my PHP, the PHP looks fine to me but I'm still kind of new to joins.

A little help?

Comment: you have to add joining condition "tags.tag_id=term_tags.tag_id"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sql query will look like this:

```
SELECT tag_name FROM tags INNER JOIN term_tags 
ON tags.tag_id=term_tags.tag_id 
WHERE term_id = ?
```

Answer (score 1):

use inner join like that :-

```
SELECT tag_name FROM tags inner JOIN term_tags on
tags.tag_id=term_tags.tag_id WHERE term_id = ?
```